# Disable CSS Animation run on page load (No JS, Only HTML & CSS)

Tags: html, css, animation, sass

I got a problem, I made a check mark CSS animation on my website, but they start on page load, and it shouldn't, it should only trigger on hovering / unhovering.
And the text need to collapse like (...) when the price goes above the description

- All the code is available here: https://github.com/Douwdy/Projet-3
- And you can get a preview here: https://douwdy.github.io/Projet-3/menu-1.html

Someone can help me to fix that ?
No Js Suggestion please

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

For CSS animations on page load your, I had a look at this and I would use `transition` & `transform` instead of `animation`

So if you remove the animations (`check-box__in` & `check-box__out`) in your css and replace with transitions below:

```
.menu-selector-box:hover .menu-selector-box__validator {
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
}
.menu-selector-box__validator {
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.menu-selector-box-text__price {
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}
.menu-selector-box:hover .menu-selector-box-text__price {
    transition: transform 1s ease-out;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
}
```

For the text issue I would suggest setting a width on `menu-selector-box-text` (I used 275px) and then on hover reduce the width (I used 225px), you can use the same transitions as above when reducing the width (`transition: width 1s ease-out;`)

Then the styles below need to be applied to the `<h5>` and the `<p>` tags.

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

[image]